# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw] Command line error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have install the window rails installer and when i execute this command

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

I am getting

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command tzinfo-data,
```

not sure what i am missing.

Comment: are you running this on command line? or it is in Gemfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you posted isn't a command, it is not meant to be run on the command line. Instead you add the line to your `Gemfile` in the root of your application and run:

```
bundle install
```

on your command line to install that gem and all other gems mentioned in the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are doing it wrong. You should add it to `Gemfile`

```
# Gemfile
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

and bundle it with `bundle install`

or run this via command line

```
gem install 'tzinfo-data' --platform=mingw --platform=mswin --platform=x64_mingw
```